# How do i inherit 2 values from method in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class a():
    def __init__(self):
        print("hello")
    def add(self,a,b):
        print("c = {}".format(self.a+self.b))
class b(a):
    def __init__(self):
        a.__init__(self)
h = b()
h.add(2,3)
```

please tell me my error code not working

> Error Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Inheritance.py", line 10, in 
>       h.add(2,3)   File "Inheritance.py", line 5, in add
>       print("c = {}".format(self.a+self.b)) AttributeError: 'b' object has no attribute 'a'

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with inheritance. You simply never define `self.a` or `self.b`. But you are getting those values in the arguments to `add` anyway; don't you just mean `format(a + b)`?

Comment: Perhaps you mean `format(a+b)` instead of `format(self.a+self.b)`, since you never define attributes `a` or `b`.

Comment: And make sure you always start your class names with Capital letter(Titlecase)

Comment: When trying to call a function you inherited from, please use ``super()`` to do delegate the function call to the parent class.

Comment: Thanks Sir for you help

Comment: Do not use `super` until you understand what that means. It is not just a drop-in replacement to save you the trouble of specifying a/the base class.

Answer (score 0):

When you define `class B` define it as `class B(A)` and it will have inherit everything from `class A`, also take note that whatever you have inside `def _init_(self)` will be executed when the instance is created.

*Using `f-strings` to print, valid for python3.6+, if not you may use your original print method

```
class A():

    def __init__(self):
        print("hello")

    def add(self, a, b): 
        print(f"c = {a + b}")

class B(A):
    pass

h = B() 
h.add(2,3)
```

Output:

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 inherit.py 
> hello c = 5
> ```

If you would like to create variables `h.a` and `h.b` you would want to take this route:

```
class A():

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        print("hello")
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def add(self):
        print(f"c = {self.a + self.b}")

class B(A):
    pass

h = B(2, 3)
print(h.a)
print(h.b)
h.add()
```

Output:

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 inherit.py 
> hello
> 2
> 3
> c = 5
> ```

Comment: This may only be valid with Python 3.6+

Comment: @gogaz I will notation to make that point, but before I do can you confirm it only works for versions 3.6+?

Comment: @gogaz checked with python2.7 docs it is valid for lower versions as well

Comment: f-strings appeared in Python3.6

Comment: @gogaz I thought you were referring to the class inheritance which was main point of OP question, the print method I don't think is going to interfere with what OP needed to know, his issue was with inheritance